# Recursividade em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, recursão

Estou com dificuldade em organizar uma fórmula de somatório recursivo em Python. Preciso calcular:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
def seq1(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    return seq1(n-1)+(-1**(n+1)/n)
```

Fico recebendo o mesmo erro para quase toda alteração:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer o cálculo, grato desde já!

Comment: Para qualquer `0 < n < 997` sua função parece funcionar (não verifiquei os resultados). Se precisa calcular para valores fora desse intervalo, recursividade não é a solução, mas para fins didáticos, leia sobre [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library./sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

Comment: Obrigado Anderson!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fórmula precisa ser necessariamente recursiva? ou seja, chamar a própria função?
acho que a forma mais elegante seria utilizar um 'for' e calcular a série numericamente.

```
def seq(n):
  val=0
  for i in range(n):
    val += (-1**(n+1)/n)
  return val
```

Comment: Precisaria, mas consegui identificar o erro, obrigado!

Comment: Encontrei dois erros na sua alternativa iterativa: (1) você não está usando o `i` na conta, mas sim a constante `n`; (2) `range` com apenas um parâmetro gera números no intervalo `[0, n)`, o que não é a intenção da fórmula, mas sim números no intervalo `[1, n]` (inclusive evitaria uma divisão por zero ao usar a variável de iteração do primeiro item que apontei)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui analisar o erro. A recursividade iria ao infinito por que não voltava a chamar a fórmula. Para curiosos, o código correto abaixo:

```
def seq1(n):
if n >= 1:   
    if n == 1:
        return (-1**(n+1)/n)
    return seq1(n-1)+(-1**(n+1)/n)
```

Comment: Ignorando o erro de indentação da sua resposta, devo discordar de que ela é a correção. Como o domínio da função é `N*`, sua solução faria apenas uma garantia de que se está trabalhando no domínio adequado. Concordo com o comentário do @AndersonCarlosWoss na pergunta